# How to build a server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I'm new to C# and decided to write a small client server chat application to approach the new language with *learn by doing*.

The question I have now is whats the best way to code the server part on.

The client is built with C# and for now a MySQL connection to my hosting server(Linux).
But i realized this is a dumb way to go at it.
So I was thinking of writing a server part that all clients connect to and that server will have a MSSQL connection and handle all the requests and chat delegation.

So the options I'm thinking about is either

- WCF Service (as I understood they can be installed on any IIS server)
- Windows Service (don't know if you can run this on hosts online)
- ASP.NET WebService (This would actually only by a website that takes requests)
- Node.js with socket.io
- Other options?

What do you guys think would be the best approach for his?

To keep in mind is that I would like this server to be hosted online without spending tons of money on a VPS-Server or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the most productive solution, you should probably go with SignalR (http://signalr.net/), or ServiceStack (https://servicestack.net).
Both "frameworks" are fully mono compatible, so you can run the solution you build on your linux-server.

As an ORM-Mapper, you could use the EntityFramework, which would allow you to use not only your linux-server, but also your MySQL-DB. See this blog-post for more details: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/04/14/entity-framework-6-on-mono/

Depending on your "other language"-knowledge, you want probabbly to start off with no framework at all, but to build everything from scratch.
Maybe it was just me, but I learned the most about how .net works, as I had to "rebuild" stuff like linq, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The **easiest** way to get started is to stay in the **Microsoft walled garden** and adhere there their ideas about how this should be done. Microsoft developer products integrate exceptionally well.

Probably a console application connecting to a WCF service connecting to a SQL Server using Entity Framework.

This is rather straight-forward to set up. Tutorials for this are available in heaps. Make sure to use recent tutorials and try to stay simple.

I advise against writing a chat because that requires either polling or a push mechanism. I think that is unnecessary for a beginner project. Write a data-driven application like a to-do list. Get fancy later. The first steps are hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider:

1. [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/)
2. ASP .Net Web Api

Windows Service is not a technology, it is may be using as host (IIS, Windows service)